# Switch input for sorting algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, insertion

I wrote an insertion sort below:

```
int i, j;
Book temp;
for (j = 1; j < books.size(); j++) { 
    temp = books[j]; 
    i = j - 1; 
    while (i >= 0) {
        if (temp.getAuthor().compare(books[i].getAuthor()) > 0) {
            break; 
        }
        books[i +1] = books[i];
        i--;
    }
    books[i + 1] = temp;

}
```

I want to be able to change it somehow so that I can run it with different factors.

`temp.getAuthor` also has `.getTitle` and `.getYear` is there anyway to adapt this code so I can run them aswell depending what the user chooses. I was looking into templates but not sure if I'm in the right area?

Comment: Are you familiar with function pointers?

Comment: Can you compile with c++11?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use so slow implementation of sorting algorithm (`O(N^2)` is a very slow). I'd recommend to do something like this:

1) Extend `Book` class by comparison operator:

```
bool operator<(const Book& rhs)
{
    return getAuthor().compare(rhs.getAuthor()) < 0;
}
```

2) Call standard sort function:

```
std::sort(books.begin(), books.end());
```

After it you can extend `operator<` to take into account other properties of a `Book` (don't forget that `std::sort` requires a strict weak ordeing comparison).

Another way (in case if it is impossible to modify class `Book`):

1) Create a function

```
bool Greater(const Book& left, const Book& right)
{
    return left.getAuthor().compare(right.getAuthor()) > 0;
}
```

2) And call it this way:

```
std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), Greater);
```

In this case you will extend the function `Greater` to support other properties of a `Book`.

Comment: While the information is correct, it's not what was asked. They want to learn how to make their own code more reusable. Not learn how to call the standard library sort.

Comment: @NirFriedman Thank you for pointing on this! From my point of view I showed how to make their code more reusable (to put all the comparison logic inside one function). But I agree with you that migration on `std::sort` is not absolutely necessery here.

Answer (score 1):

As addition to @Ilya if you're able to use c++11 you can pass simple comparing lambdas to `std::sort`

```
auto sort_by_author = [] (const Book& left, const Book& right) -> bool {
    left.getAuthor().compare(right.getAuthor()) > 0;
};
auto sort_by_title = [] (const Book& left, const Book& right) -> bool {
    left.getTitle().compare(right.getTitle()) > 0;
};
auto sort_by_year = [] (const Book& left, const Book& right) -> bool {
    left.getYear() < right.getYear();
};
```

and then just use it like

```
std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), sort_by_author);
print(books) // some abstract printing function

std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), sort_by_year);
print(books) // some abstract printing function

std::sort(books.begin(), books.end(), sort_by_title);
print(books) // some abstract printing function
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Beta mentioned, a `function pointer` could be used here:

```
bool cmpAuthor(const Book &a, const Book &b) {
    return a.getAuthor().compare(b.getAuthor()) > 0;
}
// And so as cmpTitle and cmpYear

int i, j;
Book temp;

// a function pointer named "funCompare"
// and should point to a function with 2 "const Book &" args
// like cmpAuthor
bool(* funCompare)(const Book &, const Book &);

// Point funCompare to the compare function you need
funCompare = cmpAuthor; // or funCompare = cmpTitle;

for (j = 1; j < books.size(); j++) {
    temp = books[j];
    i = j - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        // if (temp.getAuthor().compare(books[i].getAuthor()) > 0) {
        if (funCompare(temp, books[i])) {
            break;
        }
        books[i + 1] = books[i];
        i--;
    }
    books[i + 1] = temp;

}
```

UPDATE:

Inspired by @llya, you may also extend `Book` (or just edit the source code if you could) and create a compare function accepts a key argument like this:

```
bool compare(const Book & a, string key) {
    if (key == "author")
        return getAuthor().compare(a.getAuthor()) > 0;
    if (key == "title")
        return getTitle().compare(a.getTitle()) > 0;
    // ...
}
```

And the usage would be something like this:

```
if (temp.compare(books[i], "author")) {
    break;
}
```